# Convert float 27.7 to 27.70

Tags: python

can anyone tell me a simple way to print out a float 27.7 as 27.70 ?

thanks.

Comment: If it's not a printing issue, in what way do you think that 27.70 is different from 27.7?

Answer (score 8):

```
a = 27.7
print '%.2f' % a
27.70
```

Comment: Sorry Guys, I've asked the wrong question, I need to convert the float value 27.7 to 27.70, not print it!, thanks.

Comment: @Paris, `27.7 == 27.70` both mathematically and in python. The __only__ way your question makes any sense is if you want to textually represent it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're worrying about number of digits after point, you probably need use `decimal.Decimal` Cite from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html):

> Decimal numbers can be represented **exactly**. In contrast, numbers like 1.1 and 2.2 do not have an exact representations in binary floating point. End users typically would not expect 1.1 + 2.2 to display as 3.3000000000000003 as it does with binary floating point.